# Why does this code throws NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

```
public FileEntry ReadFileConfiguration(string id)
{
    string configurationPath = "conf.xml";
    XDocument data = XDocument.Load(configurationPath);
    return (from c in data.Descendants("file")
        where (c.Attribute("Id") != null && c.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals(id)) 
        select new FileEntry()
        {
            Name = c.Element("Name").Value,
            Path = c.Element("Path").Value,
            SheduledTime = Convert.ToDateTime(c.Element("SheduledTime").Value),
            Size = (long)Convert.ToDouble( c.Element("Size").Value),
            IsFolder = Convert.ToBoolean( c.Element("IsFolder").Value),
            LastAccess = Convert.ToDateTime(c.Element("LastAccess").Value),
            DoEncrypt = Convert.ToBoolean( c.Element("DoEncrypt").Value)
        }).First();
}
```

Main program is:

```
main()
{
    string id  = "C:\\Users\\Radhesh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Rme\\Rme\\test.txt";
    ReadFileConfiguration(id);
}
```

My XML page is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Files>
    <file Id="C:\Users\Radhesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rme\Rme\test.txt">
        <Name>test.txt</Name> 
        <Path>C:\Users\Radhesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rme\Rme\test.txt</Path> 
        <IsFolder>False</IsFolder> 
        <DoEncrypt>True</DoEncrypt> 
        <Size>0</Size> 
        <LastAcess>7/9/2011 11:35:53 PM</LastAcess> 
        <SheduledTime>7/10/2011 1:59:20 PM</SheduledTime> 
    </file>
</Files>
```

My class:

```
class FileEntry
{
        public string Name { get;set;}
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public bool IsFolder { get; set; }
        public long Size { get;set; }
        public DateTime LastAccess { get;set; }
        public DateTime SheduledTime { get; set; }
        public bool DoEncrypt { get;  set; }

}
```

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Can you at least take the time to format your question?

Comment: List the line# and stacktrace from the exception.

Comment: You need to pass the full path to the XML file, for example: `string configurationPath = @"C:\Users\Radhesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rme\Rme\conf.xml";`

Comment: @Shadow: depends on where the conf file is and I think `.Load()` will throw something other than NullRef when the path is wrong.

Comment: @user837472: What is your `conf.xml` data?

Comment: @Jalal: already provided in the question.

Comment: @Shadow: Path is correct and variable 'data' is loaded with xml file details.Exception is throw at return statement from select new FileEntry part.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps that @Henk Holterman suggested, and here's why you're seeing the Null Reference Exception.  In your select:

```
LastAccess = Convert.ToDateTime(c.Element("LastAccess").Value)
```

If you look at your XML file, you have:

```
<LastAcess>7/9/2011 11:35:53 PM</LastAcess>
```

You have, in a nutshell, a typo.  The select portion of the query couldn't find an element named "LastAccess", therefore throwing the Null Reference Exception.

Comment: Typos happen :)  Remember the technique @Henk gave you - sometimes the best way to track down seemingly obscure bugs is to break it down until you can find the real root cause.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit, just spotted it

```
 <LastAcess>7/9/2011 11:35:53 PM</LastAcess> 

 LastAccess = Convert.ToDateTime(c.Element("LastAccess").Value),
```

Notice:  `"Acess"` and `Access`

---

Start by breaking it down.

```
string configurationPath = "conf.xml";
XDocument data = XDocument.Load(configurationPath);
var files = from c in data.Descendants("file") select c;

Debug.WriteLine("Count = {0}", files.Count());

...
return files.First();
```

This should output 1 (or higher).

If it succeeds, add the `where` clause before the `select`.

Then change to the full select part and add the `Name = c.Element("Name").Value,` lines 1 by 1.

Comment: @harmmer Exception is thrown at return statement after select new FileEntry().

Comment: You commented under the wrong post. But this means the exception is from code that is not listed?

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I think we cannot write a query with out select statement.So breaking it itself giving error

Comment: :I didn't get you. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", this is the additional Information I am getting for the exception.

Comment: @user83: Your single, very large (too large) return statement contains a dozen candidates for the null reference. Breaking it up is the way to find it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it:)It was my mistake. it was a typo.. The select portion of the query couldn't find an element named "LastAccess", therefore throwing the Null Reference Exception. :(

Comment: Btw, I think you should accept @Henk's answer - it was his method of breaking it up that led to the discovery of the typo.